# Extract integer from a string in Oracle SQL and find and replace a specific character with another

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-replace

I am trying to extract numbers from a string comprises of alpha and special characters like
Green - 100%
Green - 90%
Red - 0%
Red - 25%
Yellow - 50%
Yellow - 75%
I tried REGEXP_REPLACE (COLUMN_NAME, '[[:alpha:]]') but this will leave - and %. Should i add two more REGEXP to replace the - and %? Or is there an effective way to do it in one function?

Also in another problem i need to identify the double quotes in a string and replace with two times of double quotes and finally wrap entire string in double quotes
eg: Example" should be converted to "Example"""
Sam"ple should be converted to "Sam""ple"

Appreciate your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract only number part please use `'[^[:digit:]]'` instead of  `'[[:alpha:]]'` with `regexp_replace()`

```
regexp_replace(column_name, '[^[:digit:]]', '')
```

You can use below query to resolve your second problem.

```
select '"'||replace('Example"','"','""')||'"' from yourtable
```

Comment: Here you with the examples. my input is like Green - 90% then output should be 90, if my input is RED - 25% the n output should be 25, if in put is Yellow - 75% then output is 75. So basically we need to take the numeric portion of the string. REGEXP_REPLACE (COLUMN_NAME, '[[:alpha:]]') is leaving the hiphen (-) and % alongside the numbers.

Comment: I realized the mistake after adding comment, so I deleted it. Anyway, thanks for your response again that confirms that I did correctly